# I have just got vs. I just got

Tags: grammar, american-english, present-perfect, present-tense

Is it non-grammatical / incorrect to say:

- I **just** received a call from my friend.
- I **just** got your email.
- I **just** read your email.
- I **just** came from a store.

Compared to:

- I **have just** received a call from my friend.
- I **have just** got your email.
- I **have just** read your email.
- I **have just** came from a store.

I looked this up as well before asking the question and learned that "have just" usage is often a British English usage. However, I am not completely sure if it is okay to omit the 'have' or not in American usage or, it is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

It’s informal to use the past simple with the adverb “just”. Adverbs that connect the past to the present are often used with the **present perfect**. Therefore, it’s correct to use:

> - I have just received a call from my friend. (*not... I just received a call from my friend*)

> - Have you seen Alison lately? (*not Did you see...*)

Other adverbs that are used in the same manner include **already, since (last week), so far, still, yet.**